# What function $I_{Q}(\omega)$ represents?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

I am working on CDF calculation questions, but got one specific example where I am not sure what function $I_{Q}(\omega)$ represents?

Ive tried to google but its not easy as I dont know name of this function.

Example:

Consider the probability space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{P})$, where $\mathbb{P}=0.1\delta_{-2\pi}+0.7\delta_1+0.2\delta_{\sqrt{2}}.$

If $X(\omega)=I_{Q}(\omega)$, then the CDF of X is?

Comment: $I_Q(\omega)$ is probably the "indicator"  (or "characteristic") function of $Q$ evaluated at $\omega$.  It evaluates to $1$ if $\omega\in Q$ and $0$ otherwise; $Q$ is almost certainly the rationals.

Comment: I've googled and assumed its rational numbers so not $\sqrt{2}  or \pi$. What am I getting as result of CDF is $F(x)=I_{[1,\infty)}(x)$, so it make sense to be set of Rational numbers.